# Adjust overlapping dates without CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on to adjust overlapping date in database tables. 
Sample data as below

```
 StartDate  EndDate   UNIT  ID
2017-06-09  2017-06-22  1A  21
2017-06-09  2017-06-30  1B  21
2017-07-01  2017-07-31  1B  21
```

Expected output:

```
 StartDate  EndDate   UNIT  ID
2017-06-09  2017-06-22  1A  21
2017-06-22  2017-06-30  1B  21
2017-07-01  2017-07-31  1B  21
```

appreciate your help on this.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Do you have a Calendar table?

Comment: @ justiceorjustus  - No I dont have , I am working on  3rd party database server with limited rights..

Comment: Why without CTE?

Comment: @Harry Merging date ranges usually have a lot of weird edge cases depending on the data... I think you should provide what you've tried and a larger set of sample data before someone will want to get into it.  For instance: Why does 1A end on the same date 1B starts, but 1B continues on the next day? Stuff like that will need to be explained or a larger example will have to be provided to figure out your logic and where the edge cases are.

Comment: @Magnus , As I said i have limited rights, sql server wont allow me to run CTE...

Comment: @justiceorjustus ,  Yes my fault , if I can get start date for 1 B from 2017-06-23 then It would also work. this is the range mistake done  in data entry by end user, so ihave to correct at once..

Comment: Is there any significance to the `UNIT` and `ID` columns or is there supposed to be no overlapping date ranges across the whole table?

Comment: @iamdave  yes there is , it would be group by Id for individual resident and  date on Units should not overlap.

Comment: What about using Cursor?

Comment: I just died a little inside @jophab

Comment: @scsimon I dont understand. Why?

Comment: What permissions do you have that wouldn't allow you to use a CTE @Harry? Plain old datareader wouldn't limit you to not use a CTE.

Comment: @jophab because they are extremely expensive for something like this, and is arguable the worst way possible to accomplish this task. Granted, I understand the option since the OP claims they can't use a CTE, which I don't understand, but still--it'd be better to load up a date table from a flat file or soemthing.

Comment: @scsimon  Devil's advocate and all, but maybe it is an in-house design choice that they won't approve code that uses a `cte`?

Comment: @scsimon Now I got it. Thanks Man :)

Comment: Fair point @iamdave though I find that very unlikely, and didn't think about that because the OP stated it was a permissions issue... *sql server won't allow me to run CTE*

Comment: @scsimon  Is it even possible to restrict `cte` use?  Quick google says no, though more than happy to learn something new...

Comment: @iamdave I don't think so, if they have datareader or explicit select granted... and I couldn't find a **documented** way to, hence my question to the OP. Smells fishy....

Comment: @scsimon   I am  sorrry for confusion. I am using third party application custom reports, in that case i have to import my sql script in their format , that restrict..

Comment: You cant restrict `CTE`  the same way you cant restrict `SUM()`. CTE are converted to sub-query by the db engine, is just another way to write the code, doesn't make any difference on performance only readability. My guess is someone on the dba has a unjustifiable fear for CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lead/lag in case of 2012+, since your are using 2008 you can query as below:

```
;With cte as (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by EndDate ) from #sampledata 
) 
Select StartDate = Coalesce (Case when Dateadd(DD, 1, c2.Enddate) = c1.Startdate then c1.Startdate Else c2.Enddate End, c1.StartDate)
        ,c1.Enddate, c1.Unit, C1.Id
    from cte c1 left join cte c2 
        on c1.RowN = c2.RowN+1
```

If you still do not want to use cte as above then you can do sub-query as below:

```
Select StartDate = Coalesce (Case when Dateadd(DD, 1, c2.Enddate) = c1.Startdate then c1.Startdate Else c2.Enddate End, c1.StartDate)
        ,c1.Enddate, c1.Unit, C1.Id
    from (Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by EndDate ) from #sampledata ) c1 
    left join (Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by EndDate ) from #sampledata ) c2 
        on c1.RowN = c2.RowN+1
```

Comment: Yep just noticed OP is asking without CTE... updated

Comment: Will this work if there is a row that's date period is entirely contained within the time period of another row?

Comment: @Juan i have partition by Id only... not sure which area you are referring

Comment: @iamdave which row you mean? Do you mean start and enddate is inside of some row?

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to @Kannan's Answer.

```
Select StartDate = Coalesce (Case when c1.Startdate <= c2.Enddate
                                  then c2.Enddate 
                                  Else c1.Startdate 
                             End, 
                   c1.StartDate)
       ,c1.Enddate, c1.Unit, C1.Id
from
    (Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by EndDate ) 
     from #sample ) c1 
left join 
    (Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id order by EndDate ) 
     from #sample ) c2 
on c1.RowN = c2.RowN+1
```